# How to display my console.log result into input type text?

Tags: javascript

I have a function where 2 data will be joined if they have the same level. My target is, how can I show my console.log result to my HTML? I want to show it in input type=" text" form. This is my current work. It only shows in "<span". Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```js
const source = [
    {id: 1, name: 'player1', level: 2},
    {id: 3, name: 'player2', level: 2},


]

//this function is for combining 2 arrays in 1 if they have the same level
const combine = (source) => {
    return source.reduce((acc,curr) => {
        if(acc[curr.level]) 
            acc[curr.level].push(curr);
        else
            acc[curr.level] = [curr];   
        return acc;
    },{})
}

//this function is for displaying console.log result to my html. But the thing is it is not in input type, it's only in the span 
(function (logger) {
    console.old = console.log;
    console.log = function () {
        var output = "", arg, i;

        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            arg = arguments[i];
            output += "<span class=\"log-" + (typeof arg) + "\">";

            if (
                typeof arg === "object" &&
                typeof JSON === "object" &&
                typeof JSON.stringify === "function"
            ) {
                output += JSON.stringify(arg);   
            } else {
                output += arg;   
            }

            output += "</span>&nbsp;";
        }

        logger.innerHTML += output + "<br>";
        console.old.apply(undefined, arguments);
    };
})(document.getElementById("logger"));

// Testing
console.log('Result', combine(source));
```

```html
<pre id="logger"></pre> // display the result here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through your array values using `forEach` loop then inside this append new inputs with values inside some variable using `+=` and then finally append this in your *DOM*.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
const source = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'player1',
    level: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'player2',
    level: 2
  },


]
const combine = (source) => {
  return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr.level])
      acc[curr.level].push(curr);
    else
      acc[curr.level] = [curr];
    return acc;
  }, {})
}
var result = combine(source)
var html = ""
var keys = Object.keys(result) //if there more then one keys i.e : 2..
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  console.log("Keys " + keys[i])
  //loop through json array
  result[keys[i]].forEach(function(val, index) {
  //check if index value is `0`..change name. 
    var ids = index == 0 ? "id[]" : "idside[]"
    var name = index == 0 ? "name[]" : "nameside[]"
    var levels = index == 0 ? "level[]" : "levelside[]"
    html += `<input type="text" name="${ids}" value="${val.id}">
<input type="text" name="${name}" value="${val.name}">
<input type="text" name="${levels}" value="${val.level}">`
  })
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html //add html to div
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, works like a magic. Additionally, is it okay for me to ask more question?

My additional target is to store the 2nd data in different input type field with different names, the one you provided is perfect for my 1st data, but for 2nd data i want to store it with different name="". 

Please see this. https://prnt.sc/16lnbnz

Comment: So, there willl always be 2 data in one json array ? :)

Comment: Yes, it is. It happens because i'm doing a matchmaking system where players with the same level will be matched, for example player 1 has level 1 and player 2 has level 2. They'll be automatically matched. That's why it'll be always 2 data in one json array. Thank you. And sorry for making it too hard.

Comment: WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. I'm just super thankful. Hope you have a great day every day. Thank you so much again <3

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

To set text inside an input element you need to use the value property.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input")
function showData() {
  input.value = "Any String value here"
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="showData()">Show Data</button>
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask you to elaborate more? :( 

My target is like this. https://prnt.sc/16lilxp 

I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`

```
   <input type="text" placeholder="enter your name" id="txtInputData">
   <button onclick="displayName()">Click Me</button>
   <p id="show_name">
   </p>
```

`

```
<script>
   function displayName() {
      var originalName = document.getElementById("txtInputData").value;
      document.getElementById("show_name").innerHTML = "Your Name is :" + originalName;
   }
</script>
```